# Java NumberFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm trying to use java's ***NumberFormat*** class and the ***getPercentInstance*** method in a program to calculate tax. What I want the program to display is a percentage with two decimal places. Now, when I tried to format a decimal as a percent before, Java displayed something like 0.0625 as 6%. How do I make Java display a decimal like that or say 0.0625 as "6.25%"?

Code Fragment:

```
NumberFormat fmt1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
NumberFormat fmt2 = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

System.out.print("Enter the quantity of items to be purchased: ");
quantity = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the unit price: ");
unitPrice = scan.nextDouble();

subtotal = quantity * unitPrice;
final double TAX_RATE = .0625;
tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;
totalCost = subtotal + tax;

System.out.println("Subtotal: " + fmt1.format(subtotal));
System.out.println("Tax: " + fmt1.format(tax) + " at " + fmt2.format(TAX_RATE));
System.out.println("Total: " + fmt1.format(totalCost));
```

Comment: You've got `NumberFormat`, but I don't see you using it anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the minimum number of fraction digits on a [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instance using [setMinimumFractionDigits(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29).

For instance:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
f.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
System.out.println(f.format(0.045317d));
```

Produces:

```
4.532%
```