# Java parsing double to string

Tags: java, string, double

i have got such part of the code:

```
double double1 = 0.000112344;
String string1 = "0.000112344";
System.out.println(String.valueOf(double1) + " : "+string1);
```

results:

```
1.12344E-4 : 0.000112344
```

The question is, how can i parse double1 to string that will show me 0.000112344?

Comment: Use NumberFormat:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649833/java-numberformat

Comment: Thanks, working great :)

Comment: In general, "parsing" refers to converting a string to some other representation. The opposite is often called "formatting" or sometimes "unparsing".

Answer (score 2):

```
double double1 = 0.000112344;
String string1 = "0.000112344";
System.out.printf("%.9f: %s%n", double1, string1);
```

```
0.000112344: 0.000112344
```

In general, `String.format("%.nf", double1)` will produce a string representation of `double1` rounded to `n` decimal places.